# Exporting Mbed code to build with in Eclipse

Tags: microcontroller, arm, programming, c++, eclipse

I am working on a project to move from the [mbed](https://developer.mbed.org) platform, to some custom hardware. I am using the nRF51822 from Nordic. I have just exported my nRF51-DK project to `GCC (ARM Embedded)` and extracted it and opened it in Eclipse. It is not building however. I am getting an error code, saying

```
[file:/Users/george/Downloads/project_1V0/nRF51822/source/nordic-sdk/components/drivers_nrf/ble_flash/ble_flash.c#1]nse/nRF51822/source/nordic-sdk/components/drivers_nrf/ble_flash/ble_flash.c:1 
make: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Should it not be flash.c ? Is there anything else I was supposed to do, rather than just running it straight out of the box?

[image: Here is my export screen - showing the options I have from Mbed]

Comment: Are you exporting your mbed project as gnu GCC and then importing to Eclipse as gnu GCC project?

Comment: @FernandoLuizCola I exported as `GCC (ARM Embedded)` and in eclipse, "create new makefile project with existing code".

Comment: what OS you are using?

Comment: @FernandoLuizCola Mac OSX

Answer (score 1):

I manage to compile a Mbed project in Eclipse. I used [Kinetis Design Studio](http://www.freescale.com/tools/embedded-software-and-tools/run-time-software/kinetis-software-and-tools/ides-for-kinetis-mcus/kinetis-design-studio-integrated-development-environment-ide:KDS_IDE) but i'm sure that you can use a normal version of Eclipse C/C++ as well.

I´ve downloaded my mbed project as **GNU (Arm Embedded)** imported the project to Eclipse as an **Existing Code as Makefile Project**.

[image: Importing project]

Configure the toolchain as **Cross GCC**

[image: choosing cross compile]

In the project properties, configure **Make**

Since I'm using Windows, I had to use the make binary from [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)

uncheck the *Use default build command* and past the path to your make binary.

[image: configuring make]

Add your compiler to the PATH. I used [GCC ARM Embedded](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded)

[image: adding compiler to the path]

Build your project

[image: Build]

I got two errors:

Program "g++" not found in PATH

Program "gcc" not found in PATH

But I guess this not a problem, just a minor configuration.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: What does `GNU GCC` mean? I don't seem to have this option? See the new image in my question for my options.

Comment: Ah yes, the GCC(Arm Embedded) option of mbed is the GNU GCC that I mention ( just look at the GNU logo on the option =D ). I will fix this in my answer =D

Comment: I am using a Nordic target (nrf51822) does that change any of the make config steps? As I can see reference to the LPC family and freescale?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards I don't think so. When you download the project from mbed as GCC (ARM Embedded) you can just compile it with a compiler and a make file. The project comes with all the target specific configuration from mbed. When you configure Eclipse ( or in my case Kinect Studio ) it will just use the make file and compile.